# Getting the number of arguments to a function at compile-time using variadic templates with argument type check in c++

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Say I have a class:

```
template<typename... Types>
class Example
{
public:
    using types = std::tuple<Types...>;
    template<size_t N> using dim_type = std::tuple_element_t<N, types>;
};
```

And I want to implement a member function that depends on the tuple element as follows, with the goal of having access to the number of arguments during compilation:

```
template<size_t N>
inline constexpr void do_stuff(const dim_type<N>& elems...)
{
    constexpr size_t size_stuff = sizeof...(elems); // <-- this is the end goal 
};
```

Problem is that this implementation of `do_stuff()` won't do. And ultimately I would like the function to work like this:

```
Example<long,std::string> ex;
ex.do_stuff<0>(3);
ex.do_stuff<0>(5,6);
ex.do_stuff<1>("a","b","c","d");
ex.do_stuff<0>("a","b","c","d"); // <-- this line should not compile
ex.do_stuff<1>(1,"b"); // <-- nor should this one
```

And inside `do_stuff` I should know at compile-time how many arguments are passed.

**One possible answer, but I'm having an issue with it:**

I figured that a proper implementation of this would require the use of variadic templates, however, I am having a problem getting the `std::enable_if` part to work:

```
template<size_t N, typename... Args,
    std::enable_if_t<static_and<std::is_convertible_v<Args, dim_type<N>>...>::value>* = nullptr>
inline constexpr void do_stuff(const Args&... elems)
{
    constexpr size_t size_stuff = sizeof...(elems); // <-- this is the end goal 
};
```

where `static_and` is:

```
template<bool Head, bool... Tail>
struct static_and {
    static constexpr bool value = Head && static_and<Tail...>::value;
};

template<bool Bool> struct static_and<Bool> {
    static constexpr bool value = Bool;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean _"only access the function using the correct types"_? Didn't you check with `enable_if`? What won't do?

Comment: I meant, it works if I remove the `enable_if` part. However, I would like to keep it so that if I call, say `ex.do_stuff<0>(1,"b")` then it won't compile.

Comment: Basically, the `enable_if` part of the statement is where the issue lies.

Comment: Then you need to provide a [mcve], and rewrite the question so its focus is "how to make the `enable_if` work"

Comment: I thought it was... It is as Minimal as I can get (notice I would accept an alternate approach to deriving the compile time number of variables, and the `enable_if` is simply one approach that I could not get to work. It is also complete, but as far as verifiable, well it needs to compile. If you have a better way to rephrase the question I'm all ears.

Comment: If its true _"the `enable_if` part of the statement is where the issue lies"_, then the other parts isn't the problem. You want to check if the types fits some criteria you set, but wasn't able to. You also didn't show the error with `enable_if`

Comment: Hope this is clearer

Comment: @AOK MCVE also has that C and V. In this case it might be essentially dumny code, but still something which would do something after fixing your problem. Your question code is incomplete, as iy is in small parts and had no main.

Comment: Now I realize that because of `using types = std::tuple<Types...>;` this isn't minimal, and I could have used less code to tackle the question and made it more to the point by just fixing a single type, say `long`. Oh well, we got somewhere eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the right way (a possible right way) is the one based on `static_and`: a variadic type list `Args` of argument that is SFINAE checked to be convertible to the right type.

I propose the following version of `static_and`

```
template <bool ...>
struct static_and : public std::false_type
 { };

template <>
struct static_and<> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <bool ... Bs>
struct static_and<true, Bs...> : public static_and<Bs...>
 { };
```

and `do_stuff()` become

```
   template <std::size_t I, typename ... Ts>
   inline constexpr auto do_stuff (Ts const & ... elems)
      -> std::enable_if_t<
            static_and<std::is_convertible<Ts, type_n<I>>::value...>::value>
    {
      // now the number of elems is sizeof...(elems) 
      // or sizeof...(Ts)
      std::cout << sizeof...(Ts) << std::endl;
    }
```

The following is a full compiling example (with compilation errors when appropriate)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>    

template <bool ...>
struct static_and : public std::false_type
 { };

template <>
struct static_and<> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <bool ... Bs>
struct static_and<true, Bs...> : public static_and<Bs...>
 { };

template <typename ... Types>
struct foo
 {
   using types = std::tuple<Types...>;

   static constexpr std::size_t num_types { sizeof...(Types) };

   template <std::size_t I>
   using type_n = std::tuple_element_t<I, types>;

   template <std::size_t I, typename ... Ts>
   inline constexpr auto do_stuff (Ts const & ... elems)
      -> std::enable_if_t<
            static_and<std::is_convertible<Ts, type_n<I>>::value...>::value>
    {
      // now the number of elems is sizeof...(elems) 
      // or sizeof...(Ts)
      std::cout << sizeof...(Ts) << std::endl;
    }
 };

int main ()
 {
   foo<long, std::string> ex;

   ex.do_stuff<0>(3);                     // compile; print 1
   ex.do_stuff<0>(5, 6);                  // compile; print 2
   ex.do_stuff<1>("a", "b", "c", "d");    // compile; print 4
   // ex.do_stuff<0>("a", "b", "c", "d"); //  compilation error
   // ex.do_stuff<1>(1, "b");             //  compilation error
 }
```

If you can use C++17, instead of `static_and` you can simply use template folding

```
template <std::size_t I, typename ... Ts>
inline constexpr auto do_stuff (Ts const & ... elems)
   -> std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_convertible<Ts, type_n<I>>::value)>
 {
   // now the number of elems is sizeof...(elems) 
   // or sizeof...(Ts)
   std::cout << sizeof...(Ts) << std::endl;
 }
```

If, in C++14, you prefer a `constexpr` `static_and()` function instead of a `struct`, you can write it as follows

```
template <bool ... Bs>
constexpr bool static_and ()
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   bool ret { true };

   (void) unused { true, ret &= Bs... };

   return ret;
 }
```

So `do_stuff()` become

```
   template <std::size_t I, typename ... Ts>
   inline constexpr auto do_stuff (Ts const & ... elems)
      -> std::enable_if_t<
            static_and<std::is_convertible<Ts, type_n<I>>::value...>()>
    {
      // now the number of elems is sizeof...(elems) 
      // or sizeof...(Ts)
      std::cout << sizeof...(Ts) << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Note that the function uses a different variadic template `Type` not `Types`. For example, I would like to be able to run: `Example<long,std::string> ex; ex.do_stuff<0>(3); ex.do_stuff<0>(5,6); ex.do_stuff<1>("a","b","c","d","e");`

Comment: @AOK - I see... so, with `N`, you want fix a type in `Types...` list and get a variadic list of that type?

Comment: Correct. The first implementation actually shows exactly what I want, but unfortunately it cannot be used to retrieve the number of arguments at compile time.

Comment: This is where some better naming would reduce confusion

Comment: I was hoping the first implementation made it clear what I was going for. But I will change some things around for more clarity.

Comment: See comments under question, the question was unclear

Comment: @AOK - so, IMHO, the way you should follow is the one based on `static_and`: a variadic list of `Args...` type and a check that they are all convertible to `dim_type<N>`; I'll try to prepare a similar example.

Comment: @AOK - answer completing rewritten; hope this helps.